# Nav Controller pop. Toolbar button disappears then reappears with direction backwards. Ionic 2

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-native

I have a button in my ionic 2 footer. It slides ok with push but not with pop and a back transition. It disappears then reappears and doesn't look great. How can I get it to slide like the forward transition does?

```
<ion-footer class="has-back-btn">
<ion-toolbar class="no-padding transparent">
<ion-buttons start>      
<button class="back-btn" tappable (click)="goBack()" ion-button icon-left>
<i class="fa fa-chevron-left " aria-hidden="true"></i> Back
</button>
</ion-buttons>
</ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
enter code here

goBack() {

  var navOptions = {
      animation: 'ios-transition',
      direction: back,
      animate: true,
  };

  if(this.isModal == true){
      this.navCtrl.pop();
  }else{
     this.navCtrl.pop(navOptions);
  }
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Please share some screenshots.

Comment: I have updated with screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont u use this

```
<button ion-button navPop>Go Back</button>
```

like the example [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/nav/NavPop/)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out but it still has the same effect.